# How to exclude child categories from get_next_post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have category a (parent category) and category b (child of category a).

I'm using get_next_post to get the next post. I need to conditionally be able to include the child category when a user is logged in and exclude it the child category when the user is logged out. I figure I could use a couple IF statements but...

The problem:
When both parent and child category are checked and I tell get_next_post to exclude the child category, it still includes it because the parent category is checked. Problem with this = I can't exclude the categories.

However, if I only check the child category and do NOT check the parent category, it doesn't include the child category at all. Problem with this = I can't find a way to include the category when I need to.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Can we see the php conditionals you use to display `get_next_post`?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude categories as a parameter of get_next_post(). Therefore, simply find the sub category ID(s) and pass them in as the second parameter of get_next_post().

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Comment: As I said, when both are checked, they don't exclude it because the parent is checked. However, when I check just the subcategory, I cannot include them back in when I need to. I need a way for it to be conditional.